# Razor view with JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, razor

Due to some limitations I'm ashamed to talk about I need to be able to have a Razor template with just JavaScript inside. This is not a problem and it works - everything is rendered properly. However inside Visual Studio the code is not 'treated' as JavaScript - syntax highlighting, navigation, formatting doesn't work. Even worse - pressing enter causes Visual Studio to freeze for 2-3 seconds and the code to be formatted according to the rules for some other language (most likely HTML).

Is there any way to hint Visual Studio to treat the whole content in the cshtml file as JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

You could trick VS into thinking it's in a script block.

Just add `// <script>` and `// </script>` to the top & bottom of the file.